# How do I make my Prism2-based wireless card work?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, kernel

I have a somewhat generic prism2-based wireless card plugged into a PCMCIA adapter. In Lucid it was working with orinoco_cs, or at least that's what it does when I boot Maverick with the Lucid kernel. However the Maverick kernel gives a message about orinoco_cs being disabled for Prism2 cards because the hostap driver supposedly supports them better.

It does look like the hostap driver is loading, and I get two devices responding to iwconfig, named wifi0 and wlan2. However they won't seem to connect to the access point.

I am using manual configuration via `/etc/network/interfaces` and the command line. At one point when the interface was down I saw iwconfig report that wlan2 had in fact connected to the access point, but when I ran `ifup wlan2` it disconnected from the AP and the rate changed back to 2M. The encryption key in the interfaces file is the same one I gave on the iwconfig command line. Further command line poking did not seem to get things associated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed hostap-utils. By itself that was not enough. Then I did the following:

(a) Changed the interfaces file to use some of the hostap_utils commands instead of some of the iwconfig-related entries.

```
auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
address desired ip
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway desired gateway address
wireless-essid my network id
# wireless-mode managed
# wireless-key my network key
# wireless-rate 11M
up prism2_param wlan2 oper_rates 15
up prism2_param wlan2 ap_auth_algs 2
up hostap_crypt_conf wlan2 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff WEP my network key
```

(b) hostap_cs was creating two network devices which were not quite independent. In the interfaces file I had settings for only one of them. From `/var/log/daemon.log` it looked like NetworkManager was trying to claim the other. I added an entry for it, rebooted, and the network seems OK now.